# Paypal success payment, get the value after user buy something in php automatic

Tags: php, paypal

how can I check if an user bought my product automatically in php/paypal?

I have a paypal button:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxx">
<input type="image" src="/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
<img alt="" border="0" src="/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and I config a return url.
but I don't know what to do next to get payment success and allow this user to access my website.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: There is a lot more to code after just the button :) A whole lot more than to cover here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for the `IPN` [instant-payment-notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) request from the PayPal servers

Here is a very simple sample based on [these samples](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php)

```
<?php
// the PHP script that is supposed to receive the IPN request 
require('PaypalIPN.php');

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */
    if(checkPriceForPayPalIPN($_POST['item_number'], $_POST['mc_gross'],$_POST['mc_currency'])){
        // correct payment, allow user to access (activate the product)
    }else{
        // the price paid for the item is not correct  
    }
}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");


function checkPriceForPayPalIPN($item_number, $mc_gross, $mc_currency)
{
    //query the database to check the price of the item here
    // --  select * from myProducts
    // where item_number = ? and mc_gross = ? and mc_currency = ?
    if($correct) return true;
    return false;
}
```