# ipn paypal not execute

Tags: php, database, session, curl, paypal

I have a problem, my website is in https but IPN does not do anything yet I check after the payment it goes well on the page here is my code:

```html
<?php
include('./config.php');
             //$bqs = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO list_commandes(nom,id_utilisateur,etat) VALUES(?,?,?)');
        //$bqs->execute(array("dessous", "2wwwù", "5")); 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
  if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  } else {w 
    $value = urlencode($value);
  }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// Post IPN back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
$ch = curl_init('https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert); 

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
        
       if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                    $test47 = "";
                 foreach($_SESSION['panier'] as $id_article=>$article_acheté){
        $pwo = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM coques WHERE id = ?');
    $pwo->execute(array($_SESSION['panier'][$id_article]['prix']));
    if($pwo->rowCount() == 1){
        $pwo1 = $pwo->fetch();
    $test47 .= $pwo1['descri']."&nbsp;".$article_acheté['nom']."&nbsp;";
        $total_panier = $pwo1['prix'] * $article_acheté['qte'];
        }
                 }
                   if(isset($_SESSION['panier'][$id_article]['promo'])){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['panier'][$id_article]['promo'])){   
        $test47 .= $total_panier+3-$_SESSION['panier'][$id_article]['promo'];
    }
  }else{
$test47 .= $total_panier+3;
}
                    $rech = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM membre WHERE email = ?');
                    $rech->execute(array($_SESSION['connexion']));
                    $rech1 = $rech->fetch();
             $bqs = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO list_commandes(nom,id_utilisateur,etat) VALUES(?,?,?)');
        $bqs->execute(array($test47, $rech1['id'], "5"));      
    }
    header("TLS/1.1 200 OK");
?>
```

I tried a lot of things nothing worked, I even helped the documentation and I even contact them but they said it was not good service like every time, I'm looking for a solution thank you for your help
Thank You

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use PDO error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php should this also be db-related. Update your question with what the errors were, if any.

Comment: check my sample example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867448/5407848) and try to reuse the `PaypalIPN.php` file hosted [on github](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php) to do the verification